# A question related to $S^{\perp}$ and closure of span of $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

This question was asked in my linear algebra quiz previous year exam and I was unable to solve it.

> Let V be an inner ( in question it's written integer , but i think he means inner) product space and S be a subset of V. Let $\bar S$denote the closure of S in V with respect to topology induced by the metric given by inner product. Which of the following statements are  true?

A $ S $=$ (S^{\bot})^{\bot}$

B $ \overline S$= $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$

C $\overline {\text{span}(S)}$=$(S^{\bot})^{\bot}$

D $ S^{\bot} $=$ ((S^{\bot})^{\bot})^{\bot}$

I was completely blank on how can I approach this problem although I have studied linear algebra carefully. Can you please tell on how I should approach the problem .

Edit : I tried It again . I marked A ,D but answer is C,D. If A is false I don't see why D must be true. So, I think I am missing some concepts.

Comment: For $A$ and $B$, do you think that the complement must be a vector space? For $D$, what happens in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$ being one-element set?

Comment: @PeterFranek Complement  will not be vector space.

Comment: Orthogonal complement is always a vector space. If $v$, $w$ are orthogonal to all vectors in $X$, then the same is true for $v+w$ etc

Comment: @PeterFranek Can you please answer this question if you got some time for it? It will be really helpful.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some more assumption, such as $V$ being finite-dimensional or at least Hilbert? Because otherwise, $C$ is false and $D$ seems quite non-trivial.

Comment: @Peter Franek No , I have typed question correct. I checked it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $S^\perp$ is defined as the set of all vectors in $V$ which are orthogonal to every vector in $S$.

In case $S$ is a
singleton, say $S=\{s\}$, then we have
$$
  S^\perp = \{x\in  V: \langle x, s\rangle =0\},
  $$
so   $S^\perp$ coincides with the null space of the continuous linear functional
$$
  x\in  V \mapsto  \langle x, s\rangle ,
  $$
and for that reason   $S^\perp$ is obviously a CLS (closed linear subspace).

For a general set $S$, one clearly has that
$$
  S^\perp = \bigcap_{x\in  S} \{s\}^\perp,
  $$
so $S^\perp$ is the intersection of a family of CLS's, and hence itself a CLS.

Notice that the right-hand-side of (A), (B), (C) and (D) all refer to the "perp" of something, so are all CLS's.

Since the left-hand-side of (A) and (B) may or may not represent a CLS, then they can't always be true.

---

Point (C) is true.  To see why,  first notice that
$$
  S\subseteq (S^\perp)^\perp
  \tag 1
  $$
for a pretty elementary reason (which
nevertheless sounds a bit like a tongue-twister):  every  vector in  $S$ is  orthogonal to anything that is orthogonal to every vector in $S$.

We then see that (1) states that $S$ is contained in a CLS, and since $\overline{\text{span}}(S)$ is the smallest CLS
containing $S$, it follows that
$$
  \overline{\text{span}}(S)\subseteq (S^\perp)^\perp
  $$

To prove the converse inclusion,  pick any vector  $x$ in  $(S^\perp)^\perp$.
A well known result about Hilbert spaces (which requires that $V$ be complete,  and hence  we need to assume it here)
states that $x$ may be written as
$$
  x=u+v,
  $$
where $u$ is perpendicular to $\overline{\text{span}}(S)$, and $v$ velongs to $\overline{\text{span}}(S)$.

Notice that, in particular,  $u$ is perpendicular to every vector of $S$, and hence $u\in  S^\perp$.

On the other hand,
since both $x$ and $v$ lie in $(S^\perp)^\perp$,  we conclude that $u=x-v\in (S^\perp)^\perp$.

This implies that $u\in  (S^\perp)^\perp \cap  S^\perp$,  so $u$ is perpendicular to itself,  whence $u=0$ and then
$$
  x = u+v = v\in  \overline{\text{span}}(S).
  $$
This concludes the proof of (C).

---

Regarding point (D) it is true even if $V$ is not complete.  It is a consequence of  the following  much more general result:

**Lemma**.  Let $V$ be any set (e.g. the inner-product space of interest here) and let $\lozenge$ be a symmetric relation on $V$
(e.g. $x\mathrel{\lozenge} y \Leftrightarrow x\perp y$).  For each subset $S\subseteq V$ define
$$
  S^\lozenge = \{x\in V: x\mathrel{\lozenge} s, \text{ for all $s$ in S} \}.
  $$
Then
$$
  S^\lozenge = ((S^\lozenge)^\lozenge)^\lozenge,
  $$
for any $S$.

*Proof*.  The tongue-twister above immediately implies that
$$
  S\subseteq (S^\lozenge)^\lozenge.
  \tag 2
  $$
Plugging in  $S^\lozenge$ in
place of $S$ in (2), we get $S^\lozenge \subseteq  ((S^\lozenge)^\lozenge)^\lozenge$.

Next observe that
$$
  S_1\subseteq S_2 \Rightarrow   S_2^\lozenge\subseteq S_1^\lozenge,
  $$
and if this is applied to (2), we get
$
  ((S^\lozenge)^\lozenge)^\lozenge\subseteq   S^\lozenge.
  $
QED

An interesting Corollary,  in a totally distinct area of Math is:

**Corollary**.   Given a ring $R$ and any subset $S\subseteq R$,  define the commutant of $S$, denoted $S'$, to be the set formed by
the elements of $R$
which commute with every element of $S$.    Then $S'''=S'$.

Comment: But the author does not mention that the inner product space is Hilbert. I thought about it and C is false in general and for D, I was not able to decide...

Comment: Hy @Peter, you are right that (C) fails for non-complete spaces.   But check the new answer to (D).  Given the elementary level of points (A) and (B) I'd suspect that the lack of the  completeness hypothesis is an oversight.

Comment: Nice, thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

The condition that $S$ is a subset (and is not, for example, given to be a subspace of $V$) is rather odd, and makes some of this problem different from standard linear algebra. In general, in any inner product space, $S^\perp$ is a closed subspace, so the right sides of each of A, B, C, and D are closed subspaces.

However, for each of $A$, $B$, and $D$ (the original version of $D$, and not the current one), it is possible for the left side not to be a closed subspace. (The example given by Peter Franek of when $S$ is a one-element set is likely the simplest.) In general, though, $\operatorname{span}(S)$ should be a subspace, and $\overline{\operatorname{span}(S)}$ should be a closed subspace, so it should seem plausible that C could be true. It in fact is, as it essentially only deals with subspaces --- see if you can prove this.

Comment: The propositions ''In general, in any inner product space, $S^\perp$ is a closed subspace'' and ''However, for $D$, it is possible for the left side not to be a closed subspace'' are contradictory.

Comment: @MessiLio At the time that this answer was posted, the left side of $D$ was $S$, not $S^\perp$. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

$A,B,C$ are false, in general, and $D$ is true. If $V$ is Hilbert, then also $C$ is true.

Let $S$ be any set, then $S^\perp$ is the set of all vectors that are perpendicular to all elements of $S$. That's usually a definition, $S^\perp := \{v\,|\,\,\forall\,s\in S\,\,g(v,s)=0\}$.

You can easily verify that this is a vector subspace. Namely, if $v,w\in S^\perp$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, then also $v + \alpha w\in S^\perp$.

So also $(S^\perp)^\perp$ is a vector subspace.

This immediately excludes $A$ and $B$, in cases when $S$ (or $\overline{S}$) is just a subset of $V$ but not a vector subspace. You can find plenty of counter-examples, for instance  $S=\{v\}$ for one vector $v\neq 0$.

$C$ is harder. The easy part is $LHS \subseteq RHS$.

Let $v$ be from the LHS. That is, $v$ is a limit of some $v_i$ such that $v_i\in \text{span}(S)$. Each $v_i$ is a combination $\beta_j s_j$ of elements of $S$. If $w\in S^\perp$, then $w$ is orthogonal to all elements of $S$ and hence $g(w, s_i)=0$ and also $g(w, v_i)=0$. Using continuity of $g$, we have $g(w, v) = g(w, \lim_i v_i) = \lim g(w, v_i) = 0$, so $w$ is also orthogonal to $v$. So $v$ is in $(S^\perp)^\perp$.

For the other implication, you need to show that a closed subspace (closure of the span of $S$ here) has an orthogonal complement. This is not always the case: [there are proper closed subspaces $Y$ such that $Y^\perp = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023061/an-inner-product-space-and-its-proper-closed-subspace-with-trivial-orthogonal-co)!

So take such $Y$ as your $S$, then the span of $S$ is $S$ and the closure of $S$ is $S$, and $(S^\perp)^\perp = V \neq S$.

However, this being said, $C$ holds under some additional assumptions, such as $V$ being a Hilbert space.

If $C$ is true, then $D$ follows easily, because it reduces to
$$
S^\perp = (\overline{span(S)})^\perp
$$
which is obvious.

In general, if $V$ is not complete, then the proof of $D$ is given by the answer of @Ruy.