# Commutant of a set of operators in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{T} \subset B(T)$ be a set of operators.

Then we define the commutatnt $\mathcal{T}' = \{ S \in B(H) : ST =TS, \forall T \in \mathcal{T}\}$.

I'm trying to show $\mathcal{T}' = \mathcal{T}'''$.

Attempt:

By definition, we have that $\mathcal{T}'' = \{ S \in B(H) : ST =TS, \forall T \in \mathcal{T}' \}$, and $\mathcal{T}''' = \{ S \in B(H) : ST =TS, \forall T \in \mathcal{T}''\}$.

"$\subset$":

Let $S \in \mathcal{T}$. Then we have $ST=TS$ for all $T\in \mathcal{T}$.

Then I'm a bit confused on what to do next, because the $\mathcal{T}'''$ I wrote above doesn't really give me a clear idea of what an element in $\mathcal{T}'''$ looks like.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We make two trivial observations:

(1) $A \subseteq B \implies B' \subseteq A'.$

(2) $A \subseteq A''$.

Your claim then follows:

By $(2)$, $A \subseteq A''$. Hence, by $(1)$, $A'''= (A'')' \subseteq A'$.

On the other hand, another application of $(2)$ yields $A' \subseteq (A')''= A'''$.

Comment: Just a remark to the OP (or whoever is interested) that these types of arguments occur frequently and even fit into the abstract framework of something called a "Galois connection". An energetic person could add "taking the commutant" as an example in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Examples .

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma**.  Let $X$ be any set  and let $\lozenge$ be a symmetric relation on $X$
(e.g.
$x\mathrel{\lozenge} y \Leftrightarrow x y= yx$, on a ring,  or
$x\mathrel{\lozenge} y \Leftrightarrow x\perp y$, on an inner-product space).  For each subset $S\subseteq X$ define
$$
  S^\lozenge = \{x\in X: x\mathrel{\lozenge} s, \text{ for all $s$ in S} \}.
  $$
Then
$$
  S^\lozenge = ((S^\lozenge)^\lozenge)^\lozenge,
  $$
for any $S$.

*Proof*.  First notice that
$$
  S\subseteq (S^\lozenge)^\lozenge
  \tag 1
  $$
for a pretty elementary reason (which
nevertheless sounds a bit like a tongue-twister):  every  element in  $S$ is  $\lozenge$ to anything that is $\lozenge$ to every element in $S$.

Plugging in  $S^\lozenge$ in
place of $S$ in (1), we get $S^\lozenge \subseteq  ((S^\lozenge)^\lozenge)^\lozenge$.

Next observe that
$$
  S_1\subseteq S_2 \Rightarrow   S_2^\lozenge\subseteq S_1^\lozenge,
  $$
and if this is applied to (1), we get
$
  ((S^\lozenge)^\lozenge)^\lozenge\subseteq   S^\lozenge.
  $
QED

---

This is based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896728/a-question-related-to-s-perp-and-closure-of-span-of-s/3921527#3921527).

Comment: Just wanted to remark that this answer also fits into the framework of Galois connections (see the comment on **QuantumSpace**'s answer). If $\lozenge$ is a symmetric relation on a set $X$, then $S \mapsto S^\lozenge$ gives an antitone Galois connection from the power set of $X$ ordered by containment to itself.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the comment.  I didn't know about Galois connection.  It is interesting to see how this very simple idea leads to facts that sound  (to me at least) much more profound.

Comment: No problem, they are certainly ubiquitous! The group/field correspondence in Galois theory is an example, hence the name, but ultimately they're not much more than a stripped down framework in which you can make arguments like the one you wrote above work. So maybe not *all* that profound.